# Chrome Extensions synchronous calls - create window only after window closed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, promise

I have this code:

```
function voteNewWindow(mailNum) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: 'http://www.google.com',
        incognito: true
    }, function (window) {
        console.log('created ' + window.id);
        chrome.tabs.query({
            active: true,
            windowId: window.id
        }, function (tabs) {
            var tab = tabs[0];
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                file: "jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
            }, function () {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                    file: "content_script.js"
                }, function () {
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
                        email: JSON.parse(localStorage.mailList)[mailNum]
                    }, function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        chrome.windows.remove(window.id);
                        console.log('window ' + window.id + " removed");
                    });
                });

            });
        });

    });
}


function execute() {

    for (var i = 0; i < JSON.parse(localStorage.mailList).length; i++) {

        voteNewWindow(i);
    }
}
```

The problem is that all windows open at the same time. I want a window to open only when the one before is closed. I want voteNewWindow() to finish all it has to do before another voteNewWindow() executes.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JavaScript Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) to the rescue!

```
function voteNewWindow(mailNum) {
  return function(){
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject){
      chrome.windows.create({
      /* ... */
                        }, function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            chrome.windows.remove(response.id);
                            console.log('window ' + response.id + " removed");
                            resolve(); // Proceed to the next
                        });
      /* ... */
    }
  }
}

function execute() {
  var sequence = Promise.resolve();
  for (var i = 0; i < JSON.parse(localStorage.mailList).length; i++) {
    sequence = sequence.then(voteNewWindow(i));
  }
}
```

See [this section](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-creating-sequences) to understand what's happening here. Basically, we're creating a chain of Promises glued together by `then`, which ensures the next one will start executing only after the previous one has finished.

If you need to do any other action after `execute()`, put it at the end of the sequence:

```
function execute(callback) {
  var sequence = Promise.resolve();
  for (var i = 0; i < JSON.parse(localStorage.mailList).length; i++) {
    sequence = sequence.then(voteNewWindow(i));
  }
  sequence.then(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [then-chrome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/then-chrome) library, that wraps chrome api in promise calls.
And your nested callbacks can be modified to something like this

```
var thenChrome = require('then-chrome');

function voteNewWindow(mailNum) {
     return thenChrome.windows.create({url: 'http://www.google.com', incognito: true})
        .then(function(window) {
            return thenChrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: window.id})
         })
        .then(function(tabs) {
            return tabs[0];
         })
        .then(function(tab) {
            return thenChrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'jquery.js'});
         })    
         ...
```