# Javascript chrome extension not processing for loop as expected

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-chrome-extension

I have a for loop iterating over an array of windows to perform checks on them. I then go on to make use of some information found in the for loop in a later function. It appears the latter function is being executed before the loop has finished which is causing buggy behaviour.

```
// Look for a existing window to add the tab to (BLOCK 1)
chrome.windows.getAll(function(allWindows) {
    for(var i = 0; i < allWindows.length; i++) {
        alert("found a window");
        if(allWindows[i].incognito == newWindowMode) {
            windowToAddTo = allWindows[i].id;
        }
    }
    alert("done looping");
});

// Perform the mode switch (BLOCK 2)
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabList) {
    // Get the url of the current tab and encode it
    currentUrl = encodeURI(tabList[0].url);
    // Check if tab is valid in both incog and normal modes
    if(invalidURL.indexOf(currentUrl) == -1) {
        if(windowToAddTo == -1) {
            alert("needs new window");
            chrome.windows.create({url: currentUrl, incognito: newWindowMode});
        }
        else {
            chrome.tabs.create({windowId: windowToAddTo, url: currentUrl, active: true});
            chrome.windows.update(windowToAddTo, {focused: true});
        }
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabList[0].id);
    }
});
```

When run, the alerts are prompted in this order when 1 window is open at the beginning:

```
"found a window"

"needs a new window"

"found a window"

"done looping"
```

Comment: I'm guessing `chrome.windows.getAll` is asynchronous, so you can't be sure the **code after it** will **execute after it**

Comment: Also using `alert()` for debugging is pretty painful; can't you use `console.log()`?

Comment: Since the tab I am debugging closes partway through the execution I can't see the console

Comment: Look at Xan's answer to this question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821829/chrome-extensions-synchronous-calls-create-window-only-after-window-closed

Comment: @Jamie The output would be in the background window console. Read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging